# Running flask on port 80 in linux

Tags: python, flask, port

There maybe previous answers to this, So redirect me please, if that's the case
I was thinking of running flask on port 80, so I checked if anything is using port 80, as it turns out nothing is running of port 80,
so when I type this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.run(debug=True, host='192.168.4.1' port=int("8081"))
```

This gives me the web page I want to display,
But when I switch to this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.run(debug=True, host='192.168.4.1' port=int("80"))
```

I am getting:

```
PermissionError : [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Is there any issue with giving flask or python3 root privileges?

Comment: Using any port under 1024 requires root privilege.

Comment: oh ok.. got it..

Comment: damn, that was a silly mistake. TY.. also its a bad idea to run flask in root mode..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need root to run at port 80.

`sudo python app.py`

Comment: Obrigado amigo, você é um amigo!

Comment: What if a `venv` is active? This no longer works...

Comment: sorry I didn't test with venv, it supposes to do not use venv when running at 80 port (prod) ?